# Spark executor failed with overflow of memory

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running my application in Spark 2.0 , I can see in my spark UI , that one executor(executor number 27) exited  due to memory exceeding issue . The executor failed while it was executing 4 task( As executor core is 4) corresponding indexes are (34,117,200,281) . In the second attempt another executor spawned in same node (cdts1hdpdn10d) could tackle the the same 4 tasks with out giving memory exceeding issue . I dont have much knowledge in code level how Spark works , but yes i know a bit in functional level .

So it would be really helpful if any one could make me understand how second attempt is running success fully .

Below are the screenshots of SPARK UI.

[image]

Comment: That's a **Spark-on-YARN** issue. It has nothing to do with "spark-sql" or "dataframe" or "Donald Trump". Please set the proper tags for your question.

Comment: Your problem is explained in detail here: http://www.slideshare.net/SparkSummit/understanding-memory-management-in-spark-for-fun-and-profit